# How to replace exact content in PHP

Tags: php

I was making an extremely simple decryption script and I can across a problem.

```
<?PHP

// Define arrays
$search = array("3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "1", "2");
$replace = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");

$display = "Please Enter Encrypted Message!";

if ($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
{
    // Get post data
    $subject = $_POST['encrypted'];


    $result = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

    $display = "Decrypted Message: {$result}";
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Encryption</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="encryption.php">
            <input type="text" name="encrypted" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?PHP echo $display; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I enter '1 7 17' in to the '' it will return 'Y D YD' where my intention is to have 'Y D N' returned.

My problem is, it is replacing any '1's with 'Y' and all the '7's with 'D' but won't detect the '1' and '7' together as '17' and replace it with 'N'.

Has anyone got any ideas on getting to to detect the exact string/int?
If anyone has got any good separation techniques when inputting the encrypted data (eg, 1 7 17 or 1, 7, 17) that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Non-ideal but quick solution - Try re-ordering the search and replace characters so that they are in reverse order of size - that way you never run into this problem.

Comment: As an alternative.  Instead of trying to do it in a single `str_replace`, loop over your input string and look up the replacements character by character, building the new string a character at a time.

Comment: @user3228721 If you have your answer please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better looping through the values you enter from your $_POST and match them up to your array values. Something like this would work:

```
// Use $search as the array key and $replace as the value
$combi  = array_combine($search, $replace);

$display = "Please Enter Encrypted Message!";

if ($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
{
    // Get post data
    $subject = $_POST['encrypted'];
    
    // Split our post data into an array
    $chars  = explode(' ', $subject);

    // Loop over each character entered and get 
    // the corresponding value back from our combi array
    foreach($chars as $char) {
        $result .=  $combi[$char];
    }

    $display = "Decrypted Message: {$result}";
}
```

If you don't need to keep your arrays separate for anything else, you could just combine them yourself and remove the array_combine. Might also be worth doing a check inside the foreach to make sure each $_POST value ($char) exists inside the $combi array - if (array_key_exists($char,$combi)) or similar. Hope that helps.

Ref: [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: Thanks, Your code worked great, thanks again, I will be sure to ask you guys in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Try re-ordering your $search and $replace, so that the larger numbers are first. You need to replace 17 before you replace 1 and 7. That way any N's will be replaced in your script before any Y's or D's.